# How to put information into array correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**UPD**: there is a strange AJAX error when I click on "Generate" button: [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/otejid).

I am doing kind of quiz questions generator just for fun: [here](https://github.com/thesiv95/quizwithgen). The problem is that I need to make right array in var `questionsChoices` and I have no idea how to loop it right. I do (You need to see all the project for better understanding =)) 
Generated string will go as AJAX query to server. Server will generate another JS file to make quiz work properly.

I've tried to change vars into **for** loop.

```
var doc = document;

        // Number of loops is exact 'cuz questions amount always will be not more than 10
        // And only 4 choices

        var questionsText = [];
        var questionsChoices = [[], [], [], []]; // 4 more arrays in array
        var questionsAnswers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                // Include checkbox
                if (doc.getElementById('include' + i).checked){

                    // Grab choices (= ALL answers)
                    // Need to put them in quotes to make correct syntax in generated JS-file
                    questionsChoices[j].push("'" + doc.getElementsByName('right_q' + i)[j].previousElementSibling.value + "'");
                    // Selected radio-button
                    if(doc.getElementsByName('right_q' + i)[j].checked){
                        // Grab questions' text
                        questionsText.push(doc.getElementsByName('q_text' + i)[0].value);
                        // Grab questions' right answer
                        questionsAnswers.push(doc.getElementsByName('right_q' + i)[j].previousElementSibling.value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        console.log(questionsChoices);

        // Make data string to send to server via AJAX
        var data = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < questionsText.length; i++){
            // New line + tab in each question
            data += "\n\tnew Question('" + questionsText[i] + "', [" + questionsChoices[i] + "], '" + questionsAnswers[i] + "')";
            // Comma at the end
            data += (i == questionsText.length - 1) ? "" : ",";

        }


        console.log(data);
```

What I expect to see (for example):

```
new Question('Question 0 Text', ['C00','C01','C02','C03'], 'C00'),
new Question('Question 1 Text', ['C10','C11','C12','C13'], 'C10'),
new Question('Question 2 Text', ['C20','C21','C22','C23', 'C20')
```

What I see now:

```
new Question('Question 0 Text', ['C00','C10','C20','C40','C50','C70','C80','C90'], 'C00'),
    new Question('Question 1 Text', ['C01','C11','C21','C41','C51','C71','C81','C91'], 'C10'),
    new Question('Question 2 Text', ['C02','C12','C22','C42','C52','C72','C82','C92'], 'C20')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're treating your questionChoices array differently than the others. Try this approach:

```
var questionsChoices = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    questionsChoices.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        questionsChoices[i].push("'" + doc.getElementsByName('right_q' + i)[?].previousElementSibling.value + "'");
    }
}
```

PS. of course you need to adjust the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Please upvote my answer and set it as an accepted answer if it solved your problem. ;)